# Bootstrap 3 - Cancel button in Dropdown Menu Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a form inside of a Dropdown element in the navbar.

I would like to include a cancel button that will close the dropdown, but have not been able to figure out how to do it.

Any help?

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6V3sw

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<!--all of this is in the jsfiddle-->
</nav>
```

Comment: show me what you have done so far...

Comment: @Mohit is correct, [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Yes create a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.com)

Comment: @Leng : Good paper you linked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/6V3sw/2/

```
$('.ddform').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('#cancelbutton').on('click', function(){
    $('#dropdownme').trigger('click');
});
```

UPDATED

Comment: Yes, that toggles the state, but then you cannot click on the dropdown again to open it back up.

Comment: Lol, all my excuses, can you see if you prefer this ? it seems to work (with chromium)

Comment: Excellent! Great work and thanks for the help. Much appreciated!